# Azure blob storage - Is there a limit to the number of files in the same folder?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am planning on using Azure blob storage as a simple file share in which the primary identifier for a file is the file name. I would like to avoid using folders to make a structure, but I am unsure if there is a limit to the number of files i can store in a single folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As such there's no limit on the number of files you can store in Azure Storage.

Each storage account has a size capacity limit which is currently 2PiB for US/Europe and 500 TiB for other regions (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits) and you can store as many files as you like as long as you don't exceed this size capacity limit.

Comment: And the reason there is no per-folder limit is because there are technically no folders. It's just part of the blob name.